# Simple Spring EL expression does not work; with error TypeMismatchException

Tags: java, spring, exception, spring-el

I have the following simple expression in my application-context.xml:

```
<bean id="instrument" class="com.ustunozgur.Instrument" init-method="initialize" scope="prototype">
<property name="age" value="#{4}"/>
<property name="name" value="Violin"/>
```

The Instrument class is a simple POJO. However, it is throwing the following error:

```
[ERROR] ...nested exception is org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: 
Failed     to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type
'int'   for      property 'age'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string:
"{4}" ->
```

Here is the initial beans declaration in my xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.0.xsd">
```

What could be the problem? I have included spring-core, spring-expression, spring-context in my pom.xml. I am not doing any configuration via code; all the configuration is done via xml.

PS: This is a command line application, can it be the culprit?

PPS: The following code works though, so it seems only the spel in XML is ignored:

```
  ExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser();
  Expression exp = parser.parseExpression("'Hello World'");
  String message = (String) exp.getValue();
```

Here is my complete application-context.xml and pom.xml: http://paste.pocoo.org/show/494260/ and http://paste.pocoo.org/show/494262/

Comment: Are you sure you're running under the right version of Spring? Being a CLI app doesn't matter.

Comment: All my artifacts reference Spring version 3.0.5. I have set up the project using Maven, so I guess it runs the correct version of Spring. Maybe the xml namespaces in my xml are old?

Comment: I have added a PPS by the way, the SPEL called from code works. So I think there is something wrong with my xml configuration.

Comment: (Can you just use `4` without the `#{}`?)

Comment: (As Sean said after my comment, you don't need it. That said, something's definitely wrong somewhere, because it works fine for me.)

Comment: Yes, I know that literal values work fine, I was just trying whether it works or not, that's why.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure you use `ApplicationContext` rather than `BeanFactory`. `BeanFactory` doesn't support some advanced features of `ApplicationContext`, including Spring EL.

**See also:**

- [3.14.1 BeanFactory or ApplicationContext?](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#context-introduction-ctx-vs-beanfactory)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was using an outdated tutorial, one for Spring 2.5 it seems.

Comment: Ah, thought I was going nuts-I never use BeanFactory, there's probably a whole range of issues I've never seen.

Answer (score 1):

For a simple numeric property you don't need expression language. Number to string conversion is handled by the default property editors.

```
<property name="age" value="4"/>
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I know that literal values work fine, I was just trying whether it works or not, that's why.